# XCode iOS — share some text to another app — only Mail and SMS options available

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, share

Good day, friends.

I am developing an iOS application and I need to share some text from it to other apps, especially social networks. I use the following code:

```
NSString *shareText = @"This is my text I want to share.";
NSArray *itemsToShare = @[shareText];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

After the code is executed, there are only Message/Mail/Copy options in the opened window.

What am I doing wrong? Twitter and Facebook are installed, of course.

Comment: Have you signed into facebook and twitter via the settings app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used this before, but might be because you are missing URL.

```
NSString *shareText = @"This is my text I want to share.";
NSURL *shareURL = @"...";
NSArray *itemsToShare = @[shareText, shareURL];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[***Check this for detailed info***](http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/)

Also I believe `[self presentViewController` should be `[self.navigationContgroller presentViewController`

---

### Edit 1

As OP was not loggedIn in Settings, hence he was not able to see the Facebook icon in UIActivityViewController.

Comment: Doesn't change anything :(

Comment: then check whether you are logged in from setting or not... you must be logged in...

Comment: You are correct. The Facebook icon appeared after I have logged in onto account in Settings.